# How to drag from a horizontal scrollable list of items in iOS, and drop them to a vertical list below, that can accept at most 4 items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

How to manage the cells when I drag and drop.Also, I want to remove item from the vertical list below by a button tap and that will add that respective item into the above horizontal list.
I want to add items in the vertical list to perform some comparisons between those items.

Comment: there is nothing we can see below.

Comment: Please update code snippet that you are trying

Comment: @TusharSharma I have not added anything below.

Comment: @iDeveloper I want to know what should I use, UIcollectionView as horizontal list that I want and UITableView as vertical list? Or some other approach?

Comment: You want drag item from collection view and drop it to tableview ???

Comment: @iDeveloper Yes, I want such functionality

Comment: Please read it https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView. Till I found appropriate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take two collection view in your UIView-

**CollectionViewA**

**CollectionViewB**

CollectionViewA is type of horizontal type.

CollectionViewB is type of vertical type.

And than follow this article [Click Here](http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-drop-between-uicollectionviews/)

Comment: I want to drag from horizontal and drop to vertical list, but NOT do vice versa, can you suggest anything to achieve that based on the article you suggested ?

Comment: Are you able to drag from horizontal and drop to vertical list?

Comment: Yes I am able to drag from H and drop to V

Comment: But I don't want to drag from V to H.

Comment: var dragAndDropManager: KDDragAndDropManager?

self.dragAndDropManager = KDDragAndDropManager(canvas: self.view, collectionViews: [horizontalCollectionView, verticalColectionView])

Comment: Sorry I can not share that

Comment: okay,  I will try, If I will find some useful solution, I will share.

Comment: Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: I tried by removing the long tap gesture recognizer too, but still tap is not removed and cell can be dragged

Comment: Do one thing, Create a method/func and call according to CollectionView style, I mean - If CollectionView is type of horizontal. than do task 1. And if  CollectionView is type of vertical. than do task 2.